# I want to turn on the light with the camera of the android terminal activated

Tags: android, kotlin

I am Japanese. Please forgive me for questions in poor English.
I couldn't get an answer on the domestic question site, so I would like to consult with overseas experts.

> Purpose

I want to start the camera of the terminal and turn on the "light next to the camera" while previewing the camera image.

> What I did

I created an app that launches the camera and previews it on the screen. The code is shown below.

```
//MainActivity.kt

package com.example.mycamera2application2

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
    lateinit var previewRequestBuilder : CaptureRequest.Builder
    lateinit var button_torch: ImageButton
    lateinit var cameraManager: CameraManager
    val textureView: TextureView by lazy {
        findViewById(R.id.textureView)
    }
    var cameraDevice: CameraDevice? = null
    var captureSession: CameraCaptureSession? = null
    var cameraId: String = ""
    var torchSw = false
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        torchCallback()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (textureView.isAvailable) {
            openCamera()
        } else {
            textureView.surfaceTextureListener = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
                override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(p0: SurfaceTexture, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
                    openCamera()
                }
                override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(p0: SurfaceTexture, p1: Int, p2: Int) {}
                override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(p0: SurfaceTexture) {}
                override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(p0: SurfaceTexture): Boolean = true
            }
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return
            }
//            cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
            cameraManager.openCamera("0", object: CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice = camera
                    createCameraPreviewSession()
                }
                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice?.close()
                    cameraDevice = null
                }
                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, p1: Int) {
                    cameraDevice?.close()
                    cameraDevice = null
                }
            }, null)
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun torchCallback() {
        cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        cameraManager.registerTorchCallback(@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        object : CameraManager.TorchCallback() {
            override fun onTorchModeChanged(id: String, enabled: Boolean) {
                super.onTorchModeChanged(id, enabled)
                cameraId = id
                torchSw = enabled
            }
        }, Handler())
        button_torch = findViewById(R.id.button_torch)
        button_torch.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("cnfig_light","config_light")
            switchLight()
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun switchLight() {
        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, !torchSw)
        Log.i("switchLight","torchSw : ${torchSw}")
    }

    private fun createCameraPreviewSession() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            return
        }
        val texture = textureView.surfaceTexture
        texture?.setDefaultBufferSize(640, 480)
        val surface = Surface(texture)

        previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
        previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

        cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(listOf(surface), object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                captureSession = session
                captureSession?.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
            }
            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}
        }, null)
    }
}
```

```
//activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/container_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#99D1D1D1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    //<SeekBar
    //    投稿文字数制限の関係で割愛...
    //    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="フレームレート"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar_frame"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_speed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="シャッタースピード"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar_speed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_iso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="ISO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar_iso"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/container_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#818181"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textureView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_torch"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/container_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container_bar"
        app:srcCompat="?android:attr/textCursorDrawable" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Error

I want to arrange a button so that the light can be turned on and off, but the moment the button is pressed, the following error occurs and the app is forcibly terminated.

```
Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: setTorchMode:1485: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user (code 7)
```

Does this mean that id "0" is already used when starting the camera (openCamera ()), so it is not possible to process with the same id when the light is on?

In that case, I am in trouble because I do not know how to specify a different id.
I haven't found an example on the net of turning on the light with the camera running, but is it functionally possible to implement it?
If anyone knows how to solve it, I would appreciate it if you could let me know. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, if you change the camera ID to "1" and the LED ID to "0", the front camera will start and the LED will also light up.
Therefore, I think that it is necessary to specify the ID and "approve" when controlling the LED.